# Trying to return a object without EntityState and EntityKey properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, csv

I'm using EF in VS 2010, with C# to return an object that I am then using [CsvHelper](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper) to write out as a CSV data file.

The problem that I am having is that EF appears to be creating two properties that are being output in my CSV file:

EntityState and EntityKey

I would like to either suppress these properties from being created with my object, or at least be able to suppress them from the CSV output datafile that I'm writting to disk.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are able to control how the CSV helper selects properties from your object, you are going to want to use [POCO entities](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/EFPocoAdapter).

Comment: Using POCO entities is the best thing to do here, but don't use the POCO Adapter. EF4 in VS2010 supports POCO entities without the adapter. If possible, use EF 4.1 or newer and the DbContext templates as described here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/15/ef-4-1-model-amp-database-first-walkthrough.aspx If you want to stick with 4.0 then look at the POCO templates--the code they generate is not as clean, but it should still solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks ajcvickers! Installing EF 4.1, and adding a "Code Generation Item" to my EDMX files, of the new ADO.NET DbContext Generator, did the trick. now my objects are returned as POCOs.